# How can I display text in TextView using jqMath

Tags: java, android

I downloaded library jqMath and added in assets folder. Then I would like to display:

[image: If ax2+bx+c=0 with a≠0, then:]

This is my code:

```
String path="C:/Users/Y700/Desktop/Test/math/app/rc/main/assets/mathscribe";

        String js = "<html><head>"
                + "<link rel='stylesheet' href='"+path+"jqmath-0.4.3.css'>"
                + "<script src='"+path+"jquery-1.4.3.min.js'></script>"
                + "<script src='"+path+"jqmath-etc-0.4.5.min.js'></script>"
                + "</head><body>"
                + "$ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $a≠0$, then: $$x={-b±√{b^2-4ac}}/{2a}$$</body></html>";

        textView.setText(js);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong. You must write correct path of jqmath in your **Android device**, not your computer, like that:

```
String path= "file:///android_asset/mathscribe/"
```